# Geo-targeting with the openx API

Tags: api, openx

I am using the openx api to insert advertisers/campaigns/banners but I cannot seem to find any documentation on geo-targeting a campaign or banner via the API.  Can this be done, or am I going to have to start injecting directly into the database.

Answer (score 2):

I did not find anything in the documentation either, however I was able to find how to do it.

Below is the java code. I used the method setBannerTargeting from BannerXmlRpcService.php.

```
        public static String GEO_CONTINENT_LIMITATION = "deliveryLimitations:Geo:Continent";
        public static String GEO_COUNTRY_LIMITATION = "deliveryLimitations:Geo:Country";
        map = new HashMap();
        public static String[] CONTINENTS = new String[]{
        "AS","EU","AF","OC","CA","SA","NA","AQ",
        };
        public static String CONTAINS_OPERATOR = "=~";
        public static String OR_LOGICAL_OPERATOR = "or";

        ..........................
        List list = new ArrayList();
        HashMap targeting = new HashMap();
        targeting.put("logical",Targeting.OR_LOGICAL_OPERATOR);
        targeting.put("type",Targeting.GEO_CONTINENT_LIMITATION);
        targeting.put("comparison",Targeting.CONTAINS_OPERATOR);
        targeting.put("data",Targeting.CONTINENTS[1]);
        list.add(targeting);

        ...........................

        map.put("aTargeting",list);

        proxy.setTargeting(bannerID,list);
```

[image]

Comment: It seems like there is far too much context lost here, could you provide just the request body or more of the code.

Comment: I've added the XML generated by the RPC call.